# IEEEtranN.bst and Babel

Tags: bibtex, languages, ieeetran

I'm trying to use the package `IEENTranN` with `natbib` for the references in my thesis document. I'm writing in Spanish so I would like, for instance, that when I cite a proceedings instead of "in IEEE 2005" it appear "en IEEE 2005", that is the translation for this.

Before I was using the `aplain.bst` style, that was aware of these changes in the bibliography but I need to write the thesis with the IEEE citation standard. Do you know if there is a workaround for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy the file `IEEEtranN.bst`, located in `/bibtex/bst/IEEEtran` of your TeX distribution, to your working directory and rename it to, say, `myIEEEtranN.bst`. (If you want to make your style available for multiple documents, the file should go in a corresponding folder of `TEXMFHOME`, the directory used for your own individual installations.) In the renamed copy, search for the section "STRING CONSTANTS". Here, you should see functions like

```
FUNCTION {bbl.in}{ "in" }
```

Replace the above code line with

```
FUNCTION {bbl.in}{ "en" }
```

Do so for every function where the string needs to be translated (there are about two dozen functions). Compile your `.tex` document using `\bibliographystyle{myieeetrann}` – your bibliography entries should display the translated strings.

Comment: I was using the same approach for `myunsrt`, but I was skeptic there was no way `babel` could be used to translate it for me (with BibTeX in my case). Is this, seriously, the only way, also in 2022?